# Probability - Defective television

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Three machines I, II, III set up the $30\%$, $30\%$ and $40\%$ respectively of the total of a television. From them the $4\%$, $3\%$ and $2\%$ respectively are defective.

We choose randomly a television and we check if it is defective or not.

a) Calculate the probability the television that we chosen to be defective.

b) Calculate the probability the television to be constructed by the machine I if we know that it is defective.

$$$$

I have done the following :

a) Is the probability equal to $\frac{4}{100}\cdot \frac{30}{100}+\frac{3}{100}\cdot \frac{30}{100}+\frac{2}{100}\cdot \frac{40}{100}$ ?

b) We have to use theorem of Bayes, right? Is it $30\%$ (that it is from machone I) divided by the result of (a) ?

Comment: Probability trees are a useful way to visualise and understand such Bayes' Theorem scenarios. If you refer to this [medical-test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4236060/21813) answer that I just wrote, the first trial {D,H} is analogously your Machines {I, II}, while the second trial {+,-} is analogously {functional, defective}.  Both P(defective|II) and P(II/defective) can be grabbed from the probability tree by adding and dividing the probabilities of associated outcomes.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :-) @RyanG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is correct.

By Bayes' Theorem, the probability that a television was constructed by machine I given that it is defective is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(I \mid D) & = \frac{\Pr(I \cap D)}{\Pr(D)}\\
              & = \frac{\Pr(D \mid I)\Pr(I)}{\Pr(D \mid I)\Pr(I) + \Pr(D \mid II)\Pr(II) + \Pr(D \mid III)\Pr(III)}\\
              & = \frac{\dfrac{4}{100} \cdot \dfrac{30}{100}}{\dfrac{4}{100} \cdot \dfrac{30}{100} + \dfrac{3}{100} \cdot \dfrac{30}{100} + \dfrac{2}{100} \cdot \dfrac{40}{100}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

a) correct

b) right, bayes theorem. the result is

$$\frac{0.04\times 0.3}{0.04\times 0.3+0.03\times0.3+0.02\times0.4}$$

Comment: So at (b) we have $$\frac{\frac{30}{100}}{\frac{4}{100}\cdot \frac{30}{100}+\frac{3}{100}\cdot \frac{30}{100}+\frac{2}{100}\cdot \frac{40}{100}}$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: see my edits. The result is the first addend in your a) result divided by a)

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)