# A question from total probability theorem and Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

**A doctor recommends a test for a particular disease for a patient having a symptom. Before the results of the test, the only evidence the doctor has to go on is that 10% having this symptom has the disease. Past experience has shown that in 99% of the cases in which disease is present the test reveals the presence of the disease. In 95% of the cases in which disease is not present test reveals the absence of the disease.**

*What is the probability that the test reveals the presence of the disease?*

*If the test reveals that the disease is present, what is the probability that the patient is actually having the disease?*

Following shows how I answered the question
[ H denotes the patient is having the disease,
N denotes the patient doesn't have the disease,
D denotes the test results]

P(D)=P(H).P(D/H)+P(N).P(D/N)
$=0.1*0.99+0.9*0.95
    =0.099+0.855
     =0.954$

Then, P(H/D)=( P(H).P(D/H))÷P(D)
$=0.99/0.954
                   =99/954$

Even though I answered, I don't know whether I have taken the correct approach.
So I need help to understand the question properly and how to do it.

Comment: This may help, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888 (Please don't post images. Write your math with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference# )

Answer (score 1):

No, you have not used correct value of $P(D/N)$ which would be $0.05,\;\; not\;\; 0.95$

However, it is so much less confusing for beginners to use  Bayes' Theorem in a more commonsense manner.

Out of $1000$ people, $100$ are expected to have the disease of which $100*0.99 = 99$ would test positive,

and from the $900$ non-diseased, $900*0.05 = 45$ would test positive

Thus P(has disease|tested positive) $=\dfrac{99}{144}$

Comment: Btw, even if you are expected to write it out in the form you wrote it, if you aren't too comfortable, (a) you could at least check it in the manner I have shown (b) the symbols you have used are a bit confusing. you could instead use $D, D^{C}, +, - $ to denote diseased, non-diseased, positive test and negative test

Answer (score 1):

We are given that
$$P(D)=0.1,\\
P(+|D)=0.99,\\
P(-|D^c)=0.95,$$ where the $+$ and $-$ signs refer to test result, while $D$ and $D^c$ stand for Diseased and Not Diseased, respectively.

> > 2. If the test reveals that the disease is present, what is the probability that the patient is actually having the disease?

The answer is technically $100\%,$ since the test has already *revealed* that the patient *has* the disease. But of course, what the author actually means is that *the test result is positive*. As such, the answer is asking for $P(D|+)$ (see below).

> > 1. What is the probability that the test reveals the presence of the disease?

The above poor phrase usage suggests that the author is here asking for $P(+).$ On the other hand, the interpretations $P(+|D)$ and $P(D\cap+)$ are also plausible.

1. $P(+|D)$ is given above
2. $P(D\cap+)=P(D)\times P(+|D)=0.1\times0.99 = 0.099$
3. $P(+)=P(D\cap+)+P(D^c\cap+) = 0.099+P(D^c)\times P(+|D^c)=\ldots$

- $\displaystyle P(D|+)=\frac{P(D\cap+)}{P(D\cap+)+P(D^c\cap+)}=\frac{0.099}{0.099+P(D^c)\times P(+|D^c)}=\dots.$

Read more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4236060/21813).